# Selecting distinct records that has last creation date in similar records

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a table: `messages` with this structure:

```
`ID`   //  auto increment
`SenderUserID`   // foreign key: `ID` from `User` table
`ReceiverUserID`   // foreign key: `ID` from `User` table
`Message`   
`DateCreated`   // timestamp
```

I need to get distinct ReceiverUserIDs from table by this conditions:

1. Sender user should have conversations with receiver users.
2. Selected distinct `ReceiverUserID` should give us last `DateCreated` message.

So in the results, I'll have user last conversations ordered by creation date DESC.

When I distinct in select query, mysql return a first record, but I need maximum `DateCreated` for selected `ReceiverUserID to get last message in top of results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `m`.`ReceiverUserID` AS `ID` FROM `messages` `m`
WHERE (`m`.`SenderUserID` = :UserID OR `m`.`ReceiverUserID` = :UserID) 
ORDER BY `m`.`DateCreated` DESC

//:UserID means LogedInUserID
```

**It is good to know It will be exactly like facebook messages board.**

---

```
ID, SenderUserID, ReceiverUserID, Message,  DateCreated
1, 12, 11, 'Hi admin', 2012-10-24 11:07:00
2, 11, 12, 'Hi guy',  2012-10-24 11:08:00
3, 11, 13, 'Hello dear customer',  2012-10-24 11:12:00
4, 11, 13, 'Are you there?',  2012-10-24 11:13:00
5, 13, 11, 'Hiiii',  2012-10-24 11:14:00  // last conversation betwen 11 & 13
```

Current logedin user id: 11

```
SELECT `m`.`ReceiverUserID` AS `ID`, MAX(`m`.`DateCreated`) as `lastmsg` 
FROM `messages` `m` WHERE (`m`.`SenderUserID` = 11 OR `m`.`ReceiverUserID` = 11) 
GROUP BY `m`.`ReceiverUserID`
```

We have problem in this section:
It is not return our last conversation between 11 and 13 when receiver user answered the sender message, It will be not seen in results

Results:

```
ID, lastmsg
12, 2012-10-24 11:08:00
13, 2012-10-24 11:13:00  // Should be: 13, 2012-10-24 11:14:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned you have to do the same with SenderUserID...

```
SELECT `ID`, MAX(`lastmsg`) FROM 
(   SELECT `m`.`ReceiverUserID` AS `ID`, MAX(`m`.`DateCreated`) as `lastmsg` FROM `messages` `m`
    WHERE `m`.`SenderUserID` = :UserID
    GROUP BY `m`.`ReceiverUserID`
    UNION
    SELECT `m`.`SenderUserID` AS `ID`, MAX(`m`.`DateCreated`) as `lastmsg` FROM `messages` `m`
    WHERE `m`.`ReceiverUserID` = :UserID
    GROUP BY `m`.`SenderUserID`
) as table2 GROUP BY `ID` ORDER BY `lastmsg`
```

Comment: It seems a good idea, but the problem is not resolved yet.
please see new details about problem in the question.

Comment: updated to your changes, you have to separate Sender and Receiver as mentioned

Comment: Good job! but has a mistake I think: 
First should be :  GROUP BY `m`.`ReceiverUserID`
Second should be : GROUP BY `m`.`SenderUserID`

I got my solution this way. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking for a way to be able to keep all of your current functionality and work flows, yet keep the data in a single table I think you're pretty close.

Instead of having the conversationId be a key to a different table, I would instead have it point to the ID of the message that began the conversation. This would create a parent-child relationship between messages that began a conversation and all those that followed after it. To be able to see all conversations, you would just select all messages where the conversationId is null. Below is a representation of a 2 message conversation:

```
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
| id | message | read | time             | conversationId | toUser | fromUser |
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
| 1  |  test 1 |  0   | (some timestamp) |  null          |  3     |   4      |
| 2  |  test 2 |  0   | (some timestamp) |   1            |  4     |   3      |
+----+---------+------+------------------+----------------+--------+----------+
```

The conversation was initiated by user 3. All messages in the conversation can be filter by conversationId. One limitation of this design is that only 2 users can be apart of the conversation.

Update

You could get the last message given a conversation id this way:

```
   SELECT id, message 
   FROM userMessages 
   WHERE conversationId = {conversationId} 
   ORDER BY time DESC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a MAX?

```
    SELECT ReceiverUserID, MAX(DateCreated) AS LatestDateCreated
    FROM messages 
    WHERE (SenderUserID = :UserID OR ReceiverUserID = :UserID)
GROUP BY ReceiverUserID
```

EDIT

Give this a try:-

```
SELECT IF( SenderUserID =11, ReceiverUserID, SenderUserID ) AS ID, MAX( DateCreated ) AS LatestDateCreated
FROM messages
WHERE (SenderUserID =11
OR ReceiverUserID =11
)
GROUP BY IF( SenderUserID =11, ReceiverUserID, SenderUserID )
```

Comment: No, It will return just last user conversation!
I need all receiver users conversations list

Comment: Edited to add the GROUP BY which I missed out by mistake

Comment: It seems a good idea, but the problem is not resolved yet.
please see new details about problem in the question.